# No FeatureTypeList in WFS published by QGIS Server!

Tags: qgis, wfs, getcapabilities

The WFS URL I'm using to get service from QGIS Server has no data about the layers and features type. It should be noted that the WMS URL is ok. Is there any problem with the URL I'm using? Should I add any further tag?

The WFS URL:

http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&MAP=E:/test.qgz

Comment: Have you activated the WFS properties in the project settings in QGIS desktop

Answer (score 0):

Before publishing the WFS by the QGIS server, the properties of the project should be set (Project-> properties-> QGIS Server).
For example which layers to be published by the WFS or which transaction is supported should be all set (as shown in the below picture).
[image: Project Properties_QGIS Server]